# Closing flyspell correction suggestions popup

Tags: key-bindings, flyspell

If I goto correct a word with `flyspell-correct-at-point`, a word suggestion box will appear, as expected. Unfortunately I cannot close this suggestion box with `escape` I have to use `C-g`.

Any ideas on how to fix this behaviour ?

Comment: It took me about a year to get used to the notion that `escape` does not behave the same in Emacs as with most other applications.  There is nothing to `fix`, because it is not broken.  It is possible to program/customize Emacs so that `escape` behaves as `C-g` in this particular circumstance, but I'll leave that to another forum participant to write-up.

Comment: For those forum participants who are wondering where the function `flyspell-correct-at-point` comes from, it is possible that the original poster has installed a library known as `flyspell-correct` (which does not ship with Emacs):  https://github.com/d12frosted/flyspell-correct

Comment: @lawlist as emacs user who came from vim and who uses evil it is kind of hard to use C-g instaed of escape, I've tried mapping `ESC ESC` to keyboard quit but it doesnt seem to work as expected

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to discourage you from changing bindings of meta keys.
I found that setting different key bindings messes up my `M-x` functionallity (for example). You will get funny behviours on all platforms. I am on Linux Manjaro, but I saw comments from Windows and Mac users getting similar issues on other posts in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649324/8544157) and for others works perfectly, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10342397/8544157)
I assume it has to do with specific emacs version and system specifications.

**The possiblilities:**

### 1.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>")      'keyboard-escape-quit)
```

This is binding escape to the `keyboard-escape-quit` which is one of the three functions that the `C-g` complies.

### 2.

This is the second:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>")      'keyboard-quit)
```

### 3.

And the third be : `M-x top-level` , that is also a form of a quit (quiting this level to go to the one above)

### 4.

Another option is:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "ESC") (kbd "C-g"))
```

for me it translated some functionality but not quitting a completion menu.

### alternatively

In most cases `C-g` can be replaced with `esc` `esc` `esc` (three escapes bound to `keyboard-escape-quit`) or `M-esc` `esc` 
Get used to `C-g` it is emacs for quit.

Comment: Hmm, I am not a big fan of the `C-g` binding and I have somehow managed to avoid using it up till now. For some reason when the flyspell suggestion box appears it seems that many keybinds are ignored. Example, I am unable to do `C-h m` or anything else in this mode. I can use escape to exit similar suggestion buffers (autocomplete etc) so I'm not sure what is different with flyspell.